Problem installing xdiagnose
I have just upgraded to Ubuntu 24.04, but unfortunately, I have encountered an error that makes my Unity desktop unusable. (Luckily, I can still get into my desktop by starting an Ubuntu session instead of a Unity session.) The desktop shows only the desktop background and nothing else, and I can´t do anything. It seems to have to do with xdiagnose_3.8.10. This package gave an error during upgrade, and also gives an error when I start an ubuntu session. I've tried to fix it from the boot menu and from the shell (after doing a sudo apt remove --purge xdiagnose), but run into the same error in both instances:
Preparing to unpack .../xdiagnose_3.8.10ubuntu0.1_all.deb ...
Unpacking xdiagnose (3.8.10ubuntu0.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/xdiagnose_3.8.10ubuntu0.1_all.deb (--unpack):
 unable to open '/usr/lib/systemd/system/failsafe-x.service.dpkg-new': No such file or directory
No apport report written because the error message indicates an issue on the local system
         Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/xdiagnose_3.8.10ubuntu0.1_all.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

I ran into this problem too during an upgrade, but was able to remove no problem: I did an apt remove followed by an apt purge.

I've tried that, but unfortunately it doesn´t work.

Same.  Ubuntu 24.04 (NOT a new installation!), xdiagnose 3.8.10ubuntu0.1 upgrade, just came out today.  xdiagnose upgrade is broken, missing "failsafe-x.service.dpkg-new".  I assume we're not the only ones.

It looks like it has been reported. https://bugs.launchpad.net/xdiagnose/+bug/2083754

Any idea what the normal response time to such bugs might be? It's fairly inconvenient that my normal desktop environment has stopped working, and I'm not sure whether it makes sense to wait for a fix to this passage. :-)

@VictorGijsbers, this should not break your desktop environment. You just can't upgrade this single package. If other packages didn't completely update because of this bug, try running sudo apt-get -f install. Any time Software Updater shows that you have additional packages to upgrade, just unselect xdiagnose, and let the other packages update cleanly. Or, use the solution provided below. sudo apt-mark hold xdiagnose.

While it's true that this does not break one's desktop environment, it's unfortunately also impossible to upgrade the Ubuntu version while a package is on hold.

see Exclude packages from `apt-get upgrade`
hold the package xdiagnose as suggested. Don't forget to unhold the package after it's fix!
sudo apt-mark hold xdiagnose

After the bug is fixed:
sudo apt-mark unhold xdiagnose


Or unhold it immediately after, so you don't forget.

I was able to upgrade by removing xdiagnose and then reinstalling it after upgrade. Fortunately it doesn't have any dependencies.
sudo apt remove xdiagnose
sudo do-release-upgrade


Before following your instructions, it would be nice to clearly understand what xdiagnose does and what could be the consequences of removing the package. Why was it there on the first place? Isn't it necessary for anything?
